# Dynamically copy primitive as well as complex object type fields in java with auto conversion

Tags: java, object, dynamic, reflection, apache-commons-beanutils

I want to **copy some fields** from one java object to other java object dynamically. **Classes of these objects are different**.

Below is the scenario

> 1. I have some resource classes with some fields. There are few fields
>      in each class which can be modified by user but these fields **are
>      not same in all the resource classes**.  List of modifiable fields
>      for each class is being maintained in some data structure.
> 2. Most of the fields are similar and some are convertible like one has 
>      primitive and other has wrapper class. Some fields should be 
>        converted from Number types to String or vise versa as well.
> 3. Most of the fields are complex object types.

Which of the libraries available today will help me copying these fields with auto-conversion where ever required and deep copy ?
Earlier I was using ***BeanUtils***  but this does not deep copy. Neither it supports auto conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I thought spring framework might help.Here's my example of spring-core-4.1.5:

*class declaration:*

```
public static class  A{
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private C d;
    private int e;
//getter&setter here

 public static class  C {
    private String aa;
    private String bb;
    private String cc;

    //getter&setter here

public static  class  B{
    private Integer a;
    private Long b;
    private Boolean c;
    private D d;
    private Integer e;

    //getter&setter here

 public static class  D {
    private Integer aa;
    private Long bb;
    private Boolean cc;

    //getter&setter here

class ObjectConverter implements  Converter<Object, Object> {
    private final ConversionService conversionService;
    private final Class targetClass;

    public ObjectConverter(ConversionService conversionService, Class targetClass) {
        this.conversionService = conversionService;
        this.targetClass = targetClass;
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source) {
        Object ret=null;
        try {
            ret = targetClass.newInstance();

            Field[] fields = targetClass.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                PropertyDescriptor sourceDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(field.getName(),source.getClass());
                PropertyDescriptor targetDescriptor = new PropertyDescriptor(field.getName(),targetClass);

                if (sourceDescriptor.getReadMethod()==null || targetDescriptor.getWriteMethod() == null) {
                    //record error here
                    break;
                }

                Class<?> sourcePType = sourceDescriptor.getPropertyType();
                Class<?> targetPType = targetDescriptor.getPropertyType();
                if(conversionService.canConvert(sourcePType,targetPType)){
                    Object sourceValue = sourceDescriptor.getReadMethod().invoke(source);
                    Object targetValue = conversionService.convert(sourceValue, targetPType);
                    targetDescriptor.getWriteMethod().invoke(ret,targetValue);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

*main method:*

```
 A orgA = new A();
    orgA.a="123";
    orgA.b="1234567";
    orgA.c="1";
    orgA.d = new C();
    orgA.d.aa="321";
    orgA.d.bb="7654321";
    orgA.d.cc="0";
    orgA.e=-99;

    System.out.println(orgA);

    try {
        ConfigurableConversionService conversionService = new DefaultConversionService();

        //if you are not satisfied with the final A result, then
        //customize your own  Boolean->String Converter;
//            conversionService.addConverter(new Converter<Boolean, String>() {
//                @Override
//                public String convert(Boolean source) {
//                    return source==null||!source?"0":"1";
//                }
//            });

        conversionService.addConverter(A.class, B.class, new ObjectConverter(conversionService, B.class));
        conversionService.addConverter(B.class, A.class, new ObjectConverter(conversionService, A.class));

        conversionService.addConverter(C.class, D.class, new ObjectConverter(conversionService, D.class));
        conversionService.addConverter(D.class, C.class, new ObjectConverter(conversionService, C.class));

        B b = conversionService.convert(orgA, B.class);
        System.out.println(b);

        A a = conversionService.convert(b, A.class);
        System.out.println(a);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

results:

A{a='123', b='1234567', c='1', d=C{aa='321', bb='7654321', cc='0'}, e=-99}
B{a=123, b=1234567, c=true, d=D{aa=321, bb=7654321, cc=false}, e=-99}
A{a='123', b='1234567', c='true', d=C{aa='321', bb='7654321', cc='false'}, e=-99}

Comment: This seems fine solution but I some questions. Why do I need to declare converters, it should automatically find the source and target class automatically.

Comment: And I am using struts framework already so May it cause some conflict if I use this library ? One more issue I find now. Source and converter classes don't have same name for some of the fields.